# Boolean Indexing in Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, indexing, boolean

```
names = np.array(["Bob", "Joe", "Will", "Bob", "Will", "Joe", "Joe"])
data = np.array([[4, 7], [0, 2], [-5, 6], [0, 0], [1, 2], [-12, -4], [3, 4]])

In: data[names == "Bob"]
Out: array([[4, 7], [0, 0]])

In: data[names = "Bob", 1:]
Out: array([[7], [0]])

In: data[names = "Bob", 1]
Out: array([7, 0])
```

I have 2 arrays and 3 Python statements here. I know that the first one would return all data values that matched with the name "Bob". But I don't know yet about the last 2 statements. The second one returned the second values of each paid of data, and the final one retunred a combination of that two values? Can anyone explain this to me, please? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know about slicing ? `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][2:]` ?

Answer (score 1):

That is slicing.

Numpy ndarrays supports [multi-dimension indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) in single brackets. Each value means a dimension.

As your array is in 2 dimension, you can provide 2 expressions `data[a, b]`

- `a` will filter the 1st dimension, select some subarrays like `data[names == "Bob"]`
- `b` will filter in the 2nd dimension, select some values on each subarrays

---

With simple lists

```
>>> values = [0,8,6,4,2,3,1,5,7]

>>> values[4]
2

>>> values[4:7] # from index 4 included to 7 excluded
[2, 3, 1]
```

Same in multiple dimensions

```
>>> data = np.array([[4, 7], [0, 2], [-5, 6], [0, 0], [1, 2], [-12, -4], [3, 4]])

# select every subarrays, but only each first value
>>> data[:, 0]
array([  4,   0,  -5,   0,   1, -12,   3])

# select every subarrays, but only each second value
>>> data[:, 1]
array([ 7,  2,  6,  0,  2, -4,  4])

# select every subarrays, but only FROM first value, so each is an array
>>> data[:, 1:]
array([[ 7],
       [ 2],
       [ 6],
       [ 0],
       [ 2],
       [-4],
       [ 4]])
```